# Display the total number from a sql column in asp.net razor

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor, sum, webmatrix

I thought this would be fairly easy to find an answer to, but I'm at a loss after looking here, W3Schools and asp.net.

I'd like to display the added total of a sql column on as cshtml website.  It's a charity event where people signup and give an amount they are going to pledge.  I basically want to say:

```
<h2>"Total Raised So Far!"</h2>
<div>sum of the Pledge column from the Players table</div>
```

I'm currently displaying all of the people registered and their pledges using the following code:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("BBBT");
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Players ORDER BY Team";
}
```

snip

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Team</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Pledge</th>
   </tr>
```

```
 @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){
    <tr>
           <td>@row.Team</td>
           <td>@row.FName</td>
           <td>@row.LName</td>
           <td>$@row.Pledge</td>

    </tr>
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way since you are already fetching all the rows that you want is to calculate the sum from the results of the query.  So i would expand the code slightly.   The line with the sum and the arrow in it uses Linq technology.

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("BBBT");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Players ORDER BY Team";
    var results = db.Query( selectQueryString );
    int SumOfPledges = 0;
    SumOfPledges = results.Sum( x => x.Pledge);

}
```

and then in the html below, exactly what you have except for the loop

```
@foreach(var row in results){
```

and finally adding where you would like it, either above or below the loop but after the code:

```
<h1>Total Pledges:   @SumOfPledges</h1>
```

Now I made the SumOfPledges an int which means integer like whole numbers.  If it can have fractional numbers in it, you might need to make it a double or decimal.  The type needs to match what's in the database.

Comment: Knox, thanks!  I'm getting this error: Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' ...  I'm actually hoping to display this on all of the pages, not just the one where I'm showing the entire table.  Is there a simple way to show that on other pages too, or is this written just to work only when the entire table is shown?  Thanks so much!

Comment: oops, that means your Pledge is being stored as a string instead of a number.  You should see if you can change the database such that Pledge is a number.   They way i wrote it, it will only work on the page where the entire table is shown.  Perhaps the simplest solution to that is to copy the code block in my answer and put on each page. You wouldn't have to show the table on each page. There's a simpler solution using what @vkp proposed, but then you have to get that working too.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you!!  That works now that I changed it to int, but it repeats itself for each entry.  So it shows the total 5 times.  Is there a way around that?  (I'm happy just pasting the code in each page like you suggested.)

Comment: Yeah, it appears that for each row (entry) in the database it will show the total.  It correctly adds the totals (Yay!), but displays it several times depending on the number of entries. I've tried putting it in tables, putting it on other pages, etc, but it's still doing that.  So, close!  Thanks again Knox.

Comment: If the total is showing up multiple times, i suspect the @SumOfPledges is inside the loop.  Move the <h1>Total Pledges:   @SumOfPledges</h1> to the very bottom of the page after the loop, which means after the last }.

Comment: Each page that only needs the total does not need the @foreach {   }   loop and it can be completely removed.

Comment: That completely does it!  I was putting it in the loop.  Knox, thank you so much for your help.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate the help of people like you in this community!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(pledge)
FROM Players 
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY Team
```

Hope this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm really new to webmatrix, more of a notepad ++ guy doing static HTML.  So, I'm not sure exactly how to use that.  Do I put that in the @{ } area and then use what to display it in the cshtml?Let's say I have 5 people playing.  Each have pledged $100 when they signed up.  So, I have a database called BBBT, a table named Players and a Column named Pledge.  I'd like to display the running total of $500.  So when new people signup, it will go up.

Comment: I am not sure about that. I can answer if it was related to sql.

Comment: OK.  Thanks!  I do appreciate it!